# Jmeter Json Extractor multiple conditions

Tags: json, jmeter

I want to extract the value of id where Principals.value.type='USER', but my json has multiple 'id' tags. i wish to extract the first one.
Note: there can be multiple jsons in the response

**Example json:**
`{"content":[{"id":"210A3A-0135-1036-90B8-0A2163","name":"xyy 927","description":"xyz Description","policy_set":"xyz2","offline_lease_period":{"value":102,"constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"is_tracked":{"value":true,"constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"validity_period":{"value":{"days":195,"type":"Relative"},"constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"principals":{"value":[{"common_name":"xyz@gmail.com","id":"8B5F4-96C2-1035-8AB7-0A2163","domain":"APRM Domain","role":"DEFAULT","email":"abc@gmail.com","updated":"2017-11-02T04:54:49.272Z","created":"2017-11-02T04:54:49.272Z","type":"USER"}],"constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"permissions":{"value":[],"constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"watermark_id":{"value":"","constraint":"NOT_CHANGEABLE"},"policy_type":"NON_CUSTOMIZABLE","created":"2018-03-09T04:41:31.277Z","updated":"2018-03-09T04:41:31.386Z"}`

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. You are missing a ']' and '}' somewhere

Comment: Will you be using JSONPath or something else?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your json is returning the error

```
 Parse error on line 1:
...3-09T04:41:31.386Z"}
-----------------------^
Expecting ',', ']', got 'EOF'
```

if you are  able to get the Id Tag using Json Extractor Then you can use variable name _Count for example [image: Image shows extracting Device ID 1]

Answer (score 0):

The relevant JSON Path query would be something like:

```
$..principals.value[?(@.type == 'USER')].id
```

[image: JMeter JSON Path Extractor]

If you want the first id you can just set "Match no" to `1` in the [JSON Extractor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor)

References:

- [JSON Path: Filter Operations](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#filter-operators)
- [JMeter's JSON Path Extractor Plugin - Advanced Usage Scenarios](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/advanced-usage-json-path-extractor-jmeter)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, Could you please explain the query ?

Comment: i wish to extract the value of first id tag i.e. '210A3A-0135-1036-90B8-0A2163'